# Golang microseconds in log package

Tags: logging, go

Golang have standard log package.
Is there a way to put mircoseconds to its output?

Standard code puts pretty useless timestamp with second precision:

```
log.Println("Starting app on", APP_PORT)

2015/07/29 19:28:32 Starting app on :9090
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Change the log flags to add microseconds. Available flags are there: http://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants

```
log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lmicroseconds)
log.Print("Hello, playground")
// 2009/11/10 23:00:00.000000 Hello, playground
```

Comment: So fast. Thank you! :)